# Order a query based on a field pointing to the same table

Tags: sql-server, database, linq, t-sql

I have a table called "Sentence" that has the following fields:

```
ID         <--- OK
NextID     <--- FK To ID
Text
```

So if I had the following records:

```
*ID*            *NextID*          *Text*
1               12                The quick
3               40                jumps over
5               null              lazy dog.
12              3                 brown fox
40              5                 the
```

If I know that the beginning of the sequence is the record with ID = 1, is there a way to order a query based on the sequence of the NextID. As with the example above, the expected result should be...

```
The quick
brown fox
jumps over
the
lazy dog.
```

I am looking for either a T-SQL statement/s or somehow do this with Linq. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A sql linked list... interesting!

Comment: In case anyone using oracle wants to do the same thing, I will mention that oracle has the "Connect By" clause that will solve this pretty simply, as well as work for more complicated tree structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @YourTable table (RowID int primary key, NextID int, TextValue varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (1 , 12  ,'The quick')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (3 , 40  ,'jumps over')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (5 , null,'lazy dog.')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (12, 3   ,'brown fox')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (40, 5   ,'the')

;with cteview as (
SELECT * FROM @YourTable WHERE RowID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT y.* FROM @YourTable y
    INNER JOIN cteview   c ON y.RowID=c.NextID
) 
select * from cteview
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 9999) --go beyond default 100 levels of recursion to 9999 levels
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowID       NextID      TextValue
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           12          The quick
12          3           brown fox
3           40          jumps over
40          5           the
5           NULL        lazy dog.

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This will work up to 100 recursions and then you will have to configure SQL Server to allow recursion depth to be higher.

Comment: you don't have to change the server default of 100. if you add _OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)_ after the _select * from cteview_ where n can be between 0 and 32,767 levels of recursion (zero has no limit)

Comment: This looks pretty neat, but I was wondering if I can translate this into a LINQ statement.

Comment: +1 very clever. I didn't know such recursive expressions were possible

Comment: Common Table Expression (CTE) in linq-to-sql?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584841/common-table-expression-cte-in-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

LINQ answer:

```
table.OrderBy(sentence => sentence.NextID);
```

Edit: I hope I answered it correctly this time:

```
class Sentence
{
    public int Id;
    public int? NextId;
    public string Text;
    public Sentence(int id, int? nextId, string text)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.NextId = nextId;
        this.Text = text;
    }
}

var Sentences = new [] {
    new Sentence(1, 12, "This quick"),
    new Sentence(3, 40, "jumps over"),
    new Sentence(5, null, "lazy dog."),
    new Sentence(12, 3, "brown fox"),
    new Sentence(40, 5, "the"),
};

Func<int?, string> GenerateSentence = null;
GenerateSentence = (id) => id.HasValue? Sentences
    .Where(s => s.Id == id.Value)
    .Select(s => s.Text + " " + GenerateSentence(s.NextId))
    .Single() : string.Empty;

Console.WriteLine(GenerateSentence(1));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give you a result of...

lazy dog.
brown fox
the
The quick
jumps over

????

Comment: using an application side solution like this, you'd have to return back the entire table and then put all the id+nextIDs back together, or you will have to hit the db with a SELECT for each segment

Comment: @KM... that is what I'm trying to avoid. Hitting the db every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LINQ to SQL/Entities, then the generated `Sentence` class should have all those properties you mentioned, as well as an entity reference to the next sentence (let's call it NextSentence) from the foreign key.

Then you can just do:

```
Sentence s = Sentences.First();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
do { sb.Append(s.Text); s = s.NextSentence; } while (s != null);
```

and `sb.ToString()` will have your answer.