# How to optimize LINQ-to-SQL for recursive queries?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the following SQL table:

```
 ObjectTable
--------------------------------------------------
|  ID      |  Name         |  Order  |  ParentID  |
|  int PK  |  nvarchar(50) |  int    |  int FK    |
```

`ObjectTable.ParentID` is a nullable field with a relationship to a different Object record's ID.  LINQ-to-SQL generates an class that looks like:

```
 public class DbObject{

      int ID { get; set; }

      string Name { get; set; }

      int Order { get; set; }

      int? ParentID { get; set; }

      DbObject Parent { get; set; }

      EntitySet<DbObject> ChildObjects { get; set; }

 }
```

When I load a `DbObject` instance, I need to be able to recursively access the child objects, so that I can write the data to a hierarchical JSON object.

- Will I execute a separate query everytime I access the elements via `DbObject.ChildObjects`?  Since DB transactions take the longest, it seems like this is a very inefficient way to load a recursive hierarchy.
- What is the best practice for executing a recursive query with LINQ-to-SQL and/or EF?
- <strike>Is LINQ-to-SQL integrated with [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)?</strike> 
  *I found [Common Table Expression (CTE) in linq-to-sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584841/common-table-expression-cte-in-linq-to-sql)*

Comment: Are you in a position to change the data model? If not, then I would think you need to go down the sql string execution path mentioned in the other question you reference.

Comment: @chrissainty, I could change the data model. Are you saying there is no situation where a hierarchical data model is appropriate?

Comment: Not saying it is inappropriate. Just it won't work with std LINQ queries. So you could change the model to make it a single LINQ query, or you could do an sproc/text query. Just depends on which way you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in our case we have created stored procedures with CTE's and put them on the l2s designer and they work like any other Table except they behave as a method rather than property and we have experienced no problem with that so far.

Comment: This is correct answer. Neither Linq-to-sql or EF has support for efficient recursive queries. Use native SQL with CTEs for that.